# Using Google service account to access gmail api from inside a contextual gadget

Tags: javascript, oauth, gmail-api, gmail-contextual-gadgets

What I would like to be able to do is access the gmail/calendar api using javascript from within a gmail contextual gadget (rather than bouncing the requests out to somewhere else).
I also want to do this using a service account for authentication so access is controlled via the gadget setup/domain and the user is never prompted for any details themselves.

The documentation around this area is a mass of out dated and confusing information, so it's hard to even tell if this is meant to be possible or not.

I have run through a number of different approaches with little success.

According to here https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/basic?csw=1 writing OAuth gadgets is no longer supported. Spent a lot of time getting nowhere with this approach before noticing that comment, and abandoning it.

Next, tried using gadgets.io.makeRequest from https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/reference/#gadgets.io but this didn't seem the right fit for what I wanted, too much of a roll your own solution. I had no success with that, so abandoned it to try something else.

Next tried gapi.auth.authorize https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication This one seemed promising at first, but I cannot find any information on using it with a service account, and I just get errors when trying to use it (but at least errors feel like moving forwards!).

My current code for this is along the lines of

```
function connectToGmail() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
}

function checkAuth() {
    var parameters = {
        client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
        immediate: true,
        output: 'embedded'
    };
    gapi.auth.authorize(parameters, function(result) {
        console.log('login complete');
        console.log(gapi.auth.getToken());
    });
}
```

but the authorize callback is never called.
Have tried adding hd:  to the parameters too, and a few other undocumented values I've seen used in my hunt for details.

In various experiments I generally this error in the browser console

> Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=**********.googleusercontent.com&response_type=token&state=1847286098%7C0.1045275236' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Fair enough, I understand the same origin part of that problem, but wish it gave me the errors thru the callback - I have no intention of opening anything here - that's why I want to use a service account!

If I manually navigate to that URL I see the broken robot page,

> 401. That's an error
>        Error: invalid_client
>        no registered origin
>
> Request Details
>   immediate=true
>   response_type=token
>   scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
>   redirect_uri=postmessage
>   proxy=oauth2relay869439690
>   state=1847286098|0.1045275236
>   origin=https://uvh02lohhb14dcmd9rb9buet1dr4b61j-a-gm-opensocial.googleusercontent.com
>   include_granted_scopes=true
>   hd=***********.co.uk
>   client_id=.apps.googleusercontent.com
>   hl=en

I don't think there's anything useful in there, just including it for completeness in showing what I've tried.

Any ideas on if this - is/should be/will be - possible, and if not any suggestions for other approaches to take?

Comment: In developers console, while configuring oauth 2.0 authorization, Did you do Your Project > APIs & auth > Credentials.Also, check this link http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2014/04/google-api-invalidclient-no-registered.html

Comment: Yes I have. The place I am putting this code above is inside a gmail contextual gadget and that does deploy and work fine using the service account I set up at the location you mention. Now I want to be able to use the same service account the contextual gadget is using to access other API's (e.g. the gmail rest api) from within that gadget. The link you mention is for when using a web application clientID, not a service account clientID.and not what I'm hoping to do.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this problem?